# MySQL: Don't display specific data if empty field

Tags: mysql

I have the following simple query:

```
SELECT Customer_FirstName, CONCAT('*', Customer_Email, '*') 
from Customers;
```

It will display something like the following:

```
John *jon@gmail.com*
Tash **
Luis **
```

As you can see, when no email address is present in the table, it displays just "**" which looks strange. I would like to display something like:

```
John *jon@gmail.com*
Tash
Luis
```

How can I omit the whole "* email *"? If I wouldn't print the asterisks, then I can simply use something like IFNULL(Customers_Email, '')

The problem is that I need to display the asterisks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE WHEN` Expression

```
SELECT Customer_FirstName, case when Customer_Email is not null then CONCAT('*', Customer_Email, '*') end
from Customers;
```

Answer (score 2):

use this :

```
   SELECT Customer_FirstName, IF(Customer_Email IS NULL OR Customer_Email = '','',CONCAT('*',Customer_Email, '*')) as Customer_Email 
   from Customers;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helped!